# Having two roles to login with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I wanted to login with two different roles that consist of administrator and user. Once they are login, they will redirect to their own page. Anyone can help me? i got no idea.

My model file

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
 var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

 var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

My app.js file

```
 var express = require('express'),
 app = express(),
 mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 passport = require("passport"),
 bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
 User = require("./models/user"),
 LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
 passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");  //libraries

 mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");  //connect to mongodb test
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //using engine of ejs file
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(require("express-session")({
secret: "wah wah wah",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// LOGIN for user
// render login form
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.render("login"); 
});

//login for user
//middleware
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "http://localhost:8082/viewImage.html",
failureRedirect: "http://localhost:8081/error" 
}), function(req, res) {

});


//sign up page
app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
 res.render("register");
});

// register post
app.post("/register", function(req,res){
User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password,     function(err, user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.render('register');
    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
       res.redirect("/success"); 
    });
});
});

app.listen(8081, function () {
console.log('ImageViewer listening on port 8081!');
});
```

Comment: It's really almost impossible to know what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add role field in your schema. On creating the user through registration , add their roles too. Then according to the user role redirect them to the pages.